# A STA threading mode thread also blocks the winform UI thread?

Tags: .net, winforms, com, sta

I am using a STA COM object from a back ground thread, one of the COM object's a method will block, when i call it from a new thread which is in STA threading mode since the COM object's mode is STA, and the UI thread seems gets blocked too, can i avoid this UI blocking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the point of STA, COM will automatically marshal the call from your worker thread to the STA thread.  So that the COM server methods are always called in a thread-safe way.  And if the method blocks, that will also block your STA thread.  Usually the UI thread.

This means for one that using this COM object in a thread doesn't actually accomplish anything.  For another that the real problem is in the COM server, it shouldn't be blocking.  Do make sure this isn't a deadlock situation.

A possible workaround is to create the COM server on another STA thread so at least your UI thread doesn't get blocked.  Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/c-webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581) for sample code.  Both the Thread.SetApartmentState and the Application.Run calls are crucial to create a hospitable home for the server.